# Spark: How to get value for each day in interval?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, spark-window-function

I have a table with values and a date starting from which this value is valid:

| param | validfrom | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| param1 | 01-01-2022 | 1 |
| param2 | 03-01-2022 | 2 |
| param1 | 05-01-2022 | 11 |
| param1 | 07-01-2022 | 1 |

I need to get values of each parameter on each day before the specified date

For example, I have to get values for 06-01-2022:

| param | validfrom | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| param1 | 01-01-2022 | 1 |
| **param1** | **02-01-2022** | **1** |
| param1 | 03-01-2022 | 1 |
| **param1** | **04-01-2022** | **1** |
| param1 | 05-01-2022 | 11 |
| **param1** | **06-01-2022** | **11** |
| param2 | 03-01-2022 | 2 |
| **param2** | **04-01-2022** | **2** |
| **param2** | **05-01-2022** | **2** |
| **param2** | **06-01-2022** | **2** |

In other words, I need to get rows for missing dates and fill values by previous value.

I use window funсtion to get last value like this:

```
val windowPartitionByCompositeKey = Window.partitionBy(CompositeKey.map(col):_*)

    spark.table("table")
      .where($"$ValidFrom" <= repDt )
      .distinct()
      .withColumn("max_validfrom", max($"$ValidFrom").over(windowPartitionByCompositeKey))
      .where($"$ValidFrom" === $"max_validfrom")
      .drop("max_validfrom")
      .show()
```

and I get next result:

| param | validfrom | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| param2 | 03-01-2022 | 2 |
| param1 | 05-01-2022 | 11 |

But I need to get value of each param on each day before the specified date.

How I can get this?